# Why ElasticsearchRestTemplate search result is diffrent from Kibana query result

Tags: java, spring-boot, sorting, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I use spring-data-elasticsearch NativeSearchQuery to build my query,but the result is different from kibana
this is my code

```
    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchRestTemplate restTemplate;

    private Page<InvitationEs> doSearchByKw(String keyword, Pageable pageable) {

        HashMap<String, Float> fields = new HashMap<>(2);
        fields.put("title", 1.0F);
        fields.put("content", 0.8F);

        FunctionScoreQueryBuilder functionScoreQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(
                boolQuery().should(boolQuery().must(queryStringQuery(keyword).fields(fields).boost(10))));

        NativeSearchQuery build = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(functionScoreQueryBuilder)
                .withPageable(pageable).withSort(SortBuilders.scoreSort()).build();

        SearchHits<InvitationEs> searchHits = restTemplate.search(build, InvitationEs.class);

        SearchPage<InvitationEs> page = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, pageable);
        return (Page<InvitationEs>) SearchHitSupport.unwrapSearchHits(page);
    }
```

the console print request body:

```
{"from":0,"size":10,"query":{"function_score":{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"坦度","fields":["content^0.8","title^1.0"],"type":"best_fields","default_operator":"or","max_determinized_states":10000,"enable_position_increments":true,"fuzziness":"AUTO","fuzzy_prefix_length":0,"fuzzy_max_expansions":50,"phrase_slop":0,"escape":false,"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"boost":10.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":1.0}},"functions":[],"score_mode":"multiply","max_boost":3.4028235E38,"boost":1.0}},"version":true,"explain":false,"sort":[{"_score":{"order":"desc"}}]}
```

when I copy this request body to kibana,the result is right,but the "searchHits" order is wrong,the ‘score’ is changed,why?

[searchHits's score and order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRmpC.png)

[kibana's result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq0mU.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the query on the same index or alias?

Comment: Yes,I am sure@Val

Comment: How is your `InvitationEs` entity defined?

Comment: Sorry,It's my fault. I saw the post request params has'search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch',so the score and order is different.but I dont know why the param auto append

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Spring probably appends that parameter automatically

Comment: This is fixed in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.3 (see issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1884). Now the default value `query_then_fetch` is used.

Comment: Thanks @P.J.Meisch .I upgrade to Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.3